# How to prevent blender 2.8 from deforming objects when rotating a bone in pose mode

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I am new to blender.

I started by creating a simple match stick, which I want to animate.
Unfortunately I get unwanted deformations when rotating a bone in pose mode.

I used 2 separate Objects. A cube as Stick and a conical sphere as head.
I added an armature with 5 bones (automatic weight) and made it parent to the stick and head.

Example 1: In default pose, the head is conical (as intended). In modified pose, it is almost round.

Then I made a new setup. Here I connected the armature only to the stick for testing. As you can see, in default pose, it is as wide as high.

When I change the pose, all parts above the used bone get much much thicker.

I have no idea, how to stop this behavier and google was also no help.

Does anybody have an idea?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably other bones (which not in the moving section) also has influence for that part. You have to remove their influences in Weigthpaint Mode.

Comment: Unfornately not. Only the small bend part is effected (red/orange in weight paint mode)